# Ring class field of a number field K

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=Q(\sqrt{-1})$. Let $m$ be  the conductor of $K$  and $m=3$, then $Cl_{m}(K)=2$. Now how to compute the ring class field of $K$

Comment: [Crossposted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/141313/1916).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141313/ring-class-field-of-a-number-field-k#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all quadratic extensions unramified outside $3$. You will end up with 
the only such field, namely $K(\sqrt{-3})$.